# How to get OData source file updated data into sink file (Azure SQL Server) using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, odata, azure-data-lake-gen2

How to get an OData source file updated data into sink file (Azure SQL Server) using Azure Data Factory?

How to create pipeline using OData source file to sink for getting updated records, using Azure Data Factory?

[image: getting this error for]

Comment: OData source file updated data - What does this mean? Could you explain in detail with what you have tried?

Comment: i'm trying to get the updated data from Source file(example old source file having 100 rows, loaded into azure sql, and now same source file added 50 rows, so i want only updated 50 rows data in that file

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 1):

In order to load data incrementally from ODATA source to SQL database, you need to have an incrementing key column in source. Incrementing key is the unique identifier that is added to each row of the table and the value will be increasing whenever new rows are added. This column will be used to identify the rows that are copied already and the rows which are to be copied to sink.

- Create a watermark table in SQL Database and insert the initial value.
- If your incrementing key is date, keep the value as `1900-01-01`. And if it is a number, start with `0`.

```sql
create table watermark_table ( watermark_column datetime2)
insert into watermark_table values  ('1900-01-01')
```

[image]

- In Data factory pipeline, add a lookup activity and create a source dataset for the watermark table.
- Then add a copy activity. In source dataset add OData connector dataset and in sink, add the dataset for SQL database table.
- In source, enter the query as `$filter=<incremental-column-name> gt '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.watermark_column}'`

Replace the `<incremental-column-name>` with the respective key column.

[image]

- Then add the Script activity and add the linked service for SQL database. Enter the script as,

```sql
update watermark_table
set watermark_column=(select max(<incremental-column-name>) from <sink-table-name>)
```

Replace `<incremental-column-name>` and `<sink-table-name>` with the respective column name and table name respectively.

This will replace the old watermark value with new value and new value will be the latest value of the row that got loaded to sink.

**Reference**: [Delta copy from a database using a control table - Azure Data Factory | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-delta-copy-with-control-table)

Comment: Could you please create one pipeline with screenshots for better understanding.

Comment: Which part of the answer needed iexplanation and picture?

Comment: What is the incremental column name?  Where can i take?

Comment: Incremental_column will have date value or any increasing number. It indicates the time at which the row is inserted

Comment: Lookup activity and source dataset, sink dataset with examples

Comment: Added screenshot of lookup activity. This will refer the data of watermark_table  which is created in sql database

Comment: i'm not get it exact solution

Comment: In your source data, There should be field which indicates the time at ehich it got inserted into source. That column is called as incremtqal-key

Comment: Based on that column only, we can load the newly inserted rows in sink

Comment: sorry Aswin, still im facing issue, how can take copy activity datasets and script activity

Comment: [Overall-pipeline-img](https://i.imgur.com/FRXIFG7.png)

Comment: Did you use copy activity in ADF for copying data from Odata to SQL? It is same as that. In addition , you need to add the query in source dataset.

Comment: Ok, I'm clear about the lookup and copy activity. But I'm confusing where can I take increment column(example) and script activity, what is the Linked service for script activity. Please share screenshot

Comment: [Script-activity-screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/jMOKNvV.png). Linked service: Azure SQL database that contains watremark-table

Comment: **But I'm confusing where can I take increment column(example)** -- Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-delta-copy-with-control-table#how-to-use-this-solution-template). Here 1st point has the sample input data. In that input data, last modify date column will be considered as incremental key column. Similarly..when new dat is added to the source..this value gets will be increasing and unique. check the 13th point  in the doc..new rows are added to the source

Comment: im getting this error[
ErrorCode=ODataRequestNotSucceeded,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Requesting response from path tblCaseSteps and query $filter=LastModifytime gt '1900-01-01T00:00:00' failed with status code InternalServerError and message {
"error": {
"code": "execute", "message": "Invalid column name 'LastModifytime'."
}
}.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.ODataConnector,'

Comment: Perhaps you do not have LastModifytime column in the source.  That is why the error message is `"Invalid column name 'LastModifytime'."`. Enter the correct column from source